# Using load testing app in docker

Tags: node.js, performance, docker, thor

I have this simple node socker seerver as follows:

```
var ws = require("nodejs-websocket")
var connectionCount = 0;
console.info("Node websocket started @ 8002");

var server = ws.createServer(function (conn) {;
    console.log("New connection", ++connectionCount);
    conn.on("close", function (code, reason) {
        console.log("Connection closed")
    });
}).listen(8002);
```

Now I want to hit this server from machines. So to mimic these machines, I am using docker. I want to create around 10 different docker containers which will hit my server.

I want to hit the server from this docker container by using the load testing tool called thor (https://github.com/observing/thor), which can be run as easily as

```
thor --amount 1000 --messages 100 ws://localhost:8002
```

So I want to created 10 different docker container and each container should use this tool called thor and hit my server with

```
thor --amount 1000 --messages 100 ws://localhost:8002
```

How can I implement such dockor containers.

PS: I am a novice here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it should be possible.

There are images available in the docker hub for node of varying size. Choose the appropriate image.

Here are the pseudo instructions to create an image that you needed.

- Get the node image
- Install thor from git(which you already have the details)
- Run the container with your command(Hoping that your websocket app might already be running)

You can do the above in two ways either doing it manually or using `Dockerfile`.

I believe that you wanted to run in multiple containers, `Dockerfile` would be good option.

If you can use `docker-compose`, since multiple containers, it would even better approach.

Hope this is helpful.